# how to change the login page of OpenErp?

Tags: xml, odoo

I am new in using OpenErp v7 and I want to modify the standard login page. I have located the /..../web/static/xml/base.xml for modifying it. I want that the user enter the name of his database manually insteed of choosing it  from a list item. How can I do this ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really easy to do , you don't need to code anything for it, OpenERP has already provision for this. To achieve this in your server configuration file add the following param

```
--no-database-list
--no-database-list  disable the ability to return the list of databases
```

This Option removes the list of DB from the view and add the text field instead which takes db name as param.

Hope this will help you, thank you

Comment: This way if you have multiple databases you will need to manually enter the database you want to use, and it will store it in a cookie on your PC so the next time you visit the login page it will be entered automatically. This is not what I want, I want to modify the xml code of the login page without using server configuration.